# BMP (OR JPG) to DDS converter programmatically

Tags: xna, image-formats

I have bmp (or jpg) file. 
I need to convert it to dds file programmatically (I can use C++, C# with or without .NET; I can try any other language if I would see some clues in it)

I know that there are software that do this, but I need it to integrate into my programm, this should be a part of a longer manipulations on my application.

BTW, my question is:
1) Are there any opensource program that does this, so I can look into the code of it?
2) Are there any tutorials found somewhere in web that can help me to write this code?

I could not found any helpfull information.

Thank you!

Comment: The dds tag is about the Data Distribution Service, not about the graphics file format. Please choose a different tag that is appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are standalone converters you can use calling them via command line, if you need a programmatically solution the easiest way I may think about is to use built-in XNA classes to do the job. Because XNA handles all these file formats you can open source .bmp and then save it back to .dds (using the [Texture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199375%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) class):

```
public static void ConvertToDds(
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, string sourcePath, string targetPath)
{
    Texture.FromFile(graphicsDevice, sourcePath)
        .Save(targetPath, ImageFileFormat.Dds);
}
```

Things changed with XNA 4.0 (these methods have been removed), try the [DDSLib](http://communistgames.blogspot.it/2010/12/dds-from-file-on-xna-40.html) to write and [Texture2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434103%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) to read:

```
public static void ConvertToDds(
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, string sourcePath, string targetPath)
{
    using (var stream = File.Open(sourcePath))
    {
        var texture = Texture2D.FromStream(graphicsDevice, stream);
        DDSLib.DDSToFile(targetPath, true, texture, false); 
    }
}
```

See linked pages for more details and examples. By the way you can't have C# without .NET!

Comment: C# without .NET is possible, for example using [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software))

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek well Mono is just another implementation of .NET Framework, strictly speaking you're right but we all know what I mean! :)